# ExtJS6: Sharing view's viewmodel and controller with modal window

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a view having form, the view also have a modal window attached. Model window gets opened on click (via handler from controller) like this

```
this.getView().add({
  xtype: 'settings_modal'
}).show();
```

Within modal I can not access to `viewModel` or `controller`. How could we share view's binding to it child windows

Answer (score 2):

I have succesfully passed the viewController, just adding it to the configuration, like this:

```
this.getView().add({
  xtype: 'settings_modal',
  viewController: this
}).show();
```

However, I think it's better to add the modal to the view definition, hidden by default.

```
Ext.define('My.view.form', {
...
    items[
    ...
    ,{
        xtype: 'settings_modal',
        hidden: true
    }]
});
```

This way, the viewModel and controller will be shared by default.

Comment: I agree. I don't think VIewModels and ViewControllers are meant to be shared. A ViewModel's data is already shared with ViewModel's of child views.